# Rollover condition check in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements

> current and stored both are 16 bit variables.
>       The problem is this condition will fail when stored is 65535 and current is 3 as the answer
>       will be negative.

```
stored=current; 

if(stored==0)
{
    process the condition;
}          

else if(current-stored>3)
{
    process the condition;
}
else 
{
    reject;
}
```

How to check this condition?

Comment: Signed or unsigned variables?

Comment: Well, since the answer might become negative, I guess that variables are signed.

Answer (score 0):

As you have

```
stored=current;
```

Then this condition is always false

```
current-stored>3
```

Hence if `stored` is zero you do the business otherwise reject

**EDIT**

Why not read the homework question

Remove the `stored=current` - Why did you put that in?

The have an if statement

```
if (stored  == 65535 && current == 3) {
   .. reject 
} else {
   .. process condition
}
```

You could use de-morgans law to swap those around if one desires

Comment: what i want to do this is: initially i have put current in stored.

After that current will increase and if the difference is greater then 3 it will process the condition otherwise reject.can u pls tell how to perform this check

Comment: @user2067972 - This statement `stored=current;` says they are the same value from there onwards (until you change either of them)

Comment: so how to check this condition also.plz tell
this current keeps on increasing and i wan tto check the difference

Comment: 1. stored will not get any value by itself.Initially itr will be   zero. From current only it willtake the value.
 

and also i wnat to check the condition greater then 3 and this change will work if stored=65533 and current ==1 than this will not work

Comment: Please rewrite the question

Comment: the stored variable will not get value by itself and inotaially it is zero. Only current will be put in stored and current keeps on changing.

also i have to check the difference between which should be greater than 3.

Comment: the solution u have provided will work only for one case but when stored==65533 and current ==1 it will fail.

Comment: As per the statement at the top of the question. I do not know what precedes it or its context.

Comment: ok if we remove the stored=current condition then what will be the solution for the above problem